# How to get rank based on 2 column with datetime and date in Excel

Tags: excel-formula

I have a data set below and would like to get a ranking based on datetime and date. Hence, I would like to seek for advise that which formula able to suit with the expected result.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use COUNTIFS():

```
=COUNTIFS(B:B,B2,A:A,"<="&A2)
```

Put that in C2 and copy down.